# To run ant commands through batch file

Tags: tomcat, ant, batch-file

Please tell me how to call a command "ant deploy-hibernate" through batch file located in c: and i want to run the above command on trunk folder located in d: drive.The pupose is i want to run this command every time before i call a start-up for tomcat.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d d:\trunk
call c:\path\to\ant\bin\ant.bat deploy-hibernate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Ant\bin` to your PATH environment variable.